# Search for calls to method in C# programatically

Tags: c#-3.0

I want to programatically search my code base for references to a certain C# DateTime method that people on the project I am working on should not use.

I will then hook this up to my build process

Is there a way I can do this without a C# recursive directory search?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) and [create your own rule](http://stylecopplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20Create%20StyleCop%20Custom%20Rule).